duplicate symbols mac os in C
I have big problem, i have program and it scans all your pc, finds duplicate files (same content int files) and create hardlink instead this file. I use SHA256 to calculate control sum to compare with other files. My programm consists of 6 files: Cleaner.c Cleaner.h SHA256.c SHA256.h HashMap.c HashMap.h main.c. And i have a problem when i am trying to compile it. I have error:
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o program main.o Cleaner.o HashMap.o SHA256.o
duplicate symbol '_k' in:
    main.o
    Cleaner.o
duplicate symbol '_k' in:
    main.o
    HashMap.o
duplicate symbol '_k' in:
    main.o
    SHA256.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried to use Makefile.
This is Makefile:
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra

all: program

program: main.o Cleaner.o HashMap.o SHA256.o
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o program main.o Cleaner.o HashMap.o SHA256.o

main.o: main.c Cleaner.h HashMap.h SHA256.h
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

Cleaner.o: Cleaner.c Cleaner.h
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Cleaner.c

HashMap.o: HashMap.c HashMap.h
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c HashMap.c

SHA256.o: SHA256.c SHA256.h
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c SHA256.c

clean:
 rm -f program *.o

I dont know where is this symbol "_k", maybe in SHA256.h, there
typedef struct
{
 uchar data[64];
 uint datalen;
 uint bitlen[2];
 uint state[8];
} SHA256_CTX;

uint k[64] = {
 0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
 0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
 0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
 0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
 0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
 0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
 0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
 0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2};
void SHA256Transform(SHA256_CTX *ctx, uchar data[]);
void SHA256Init(SHA256_CTX *ctx);
void SHA256Update(SHA256_CTX *ctx, uchar data[], uint len);
void SHA256Final(SHA256_CTX *ctx, uchar hash[]);
char *SHA256(char *data, long strlen);

I took this implementation of SHA256 from this site https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/sha256/c/
I tried to use GCC but i have another error:
black_daddy@air-aleksandr Куровая работа ОСИСП % gcc -o *.c    
SHA256.c:120:21: warning: passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'unsigned char *' converts between pointers to integer types where one is of the unique plain 'char' type and the other is not [-Wpointer-sign]
        SHA256Update(&ctx, data, strlen);
                           ^~~~
SHA256.c:59:42: note: passing argument to parameter 'data' here
void SHA256Update(SHA256_CTX *ctx, uchar data[], uint len)
                                         ^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_readFilesInDirectory", referenced from:
      _main in main-d6f236.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

I think it cause by wrong linking, because obj files were created.

When you #include a file, its contents are directly, well, included. So you have two files defining a global variable named k, which isn't allowed by C.

Does this answer your question? How do I use extern to share variables between source files?

...or using include guards, if you don't want to modify SHA256.c?


I think it cause by wrong linking, because obj files were created.

The issue was detected at link time, but it was caused by incorrect code.  Every version of the C language spec has this provision or one substantially equivalent to it:

If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an
expression (other than as part of the operand of a sizeof or
_Alignof operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in
the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for
the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.

(C17 6.9/5)
The ...
uint k[64] = {
[...]
}

... in the header presented provides a declaration of k with external linkage that is also a definition, in every source file that #includes that header, directly or indirectly.  Therefore, if more than one translation unit of the program includes that header, and at least one accesses k, then the program thereby violates the language spec.  The resulting behavior is undefined.  From the diagnostics emitted by your compiler, you have four different translation units that #include the header, and apparently at least one of them accesses k (possibly via one of the declared functions).
Historically, some C implementations have accepted programs with this kind of issue.  You might be able to induce yours to do by adding -fcommon to your compile and (especially) link flags.
Better, however, would be to fix the code by moving the definition of k to one of the C source files, and changing the header to provide only an extern declaration without any initializer.
